# Check-all checkbox is not changes object properties from select

Tags: angularjs

[My Code - Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P5hBFam0aDswIts9a0jr?p=preview)

I'm trying to changes status of all my `list` `objects` by using a master `checkbox` that
checks all `objects` and changes their properties by selecting the required status from the 
`select element`.

The problem is that when I'm trying to apply change on all `elements` by using the "Check All" 'checkbox' it is not working.

**e.g.**

[image: Example]

When I check manually all the `checkboxes` without using the master `checkbox` it is working.

**My Code**

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);

//controllers
webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope, Votes) {
    $scope.votes  = Votes;

    $scope.statuses = ["Approved","Pending","Trash","Spam"];

    $scope.expand = function(vote) {
       console.log("show");
       $scope.vote = vote;
       $scope.ip = vote.ip;
       $scope.date = vote.created;

    };

    $scope.change = function() {
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.votes.length; i++) {
        if($scope.votes[i].cb) {
            $scope.votes[i].status = $scope.votes.status;
            $scope.votes[i].cb = false;
        }
          $scope.show = false;
      }
    };

});

//services
webApp.factory('Votes', [function() {

    //temporary repository till integration with DB this will be translated into restful get query
    var votes = [
        {
            id: '1',
            created: 1381583344653,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 5,
            ip: '198.168.0.0',
            status: 'Pending',
        },
        {
            id: '111',
            created: 1381583344653,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '4',
            rate: 5,
            ip: '198.168.0.1',
            status: 'Spam'    

        },
        {
            id: '2',
            created: 1382387322693,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 1,
            ip: '198.168.0.2',
            status: 'Approved'

        },
        {

            id: '4',
            created: 1382387322693,
            updated: '222212',
            ratingID: '3',
            rate: 1,
            ip: '198.168.0.3',
            status: 'Spam'
        }
    ];
    return votes;
}]);
```

**My HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller='VotesCtrl'>
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li class="check" ng-click=>
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"></input>
        </li>
        <li class="created">
            <a>CREATED</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            <b>IP ADDRESS</b>
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            <b>STATUS</b>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-repeat="vote in votes">
        <li class="check">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vote.cb" ng-checked="master"></input>
        </li>
        <li  class="created">
            <a href="#" ng-click="expand(vote)">{{vote.created|date}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="ip">
            {{vote.ip}}
        </li>
        <li class="status">
            {{vote.status}}
        </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <br></br>
   <div class="details">
    <h3>Details:</h3>
      <div>DATE: {{date|date}}</div>
      <div>IP: {{ip}}</div>
      <div>STATUS: 
        <select ng-change="change()" ng-init="votes.status='Approved'" 
          ng-model="votes.status" 
          ng-options="status for status in statuses">
        </select>
       <p>{{vote.status|json}}</p>
      </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

Why is master `checkbox` not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed your method `change` a bit to make it work.

From Plunker you can see that on *master* change all children still have old value. So I added `onMasterChange` method

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       ng-model="master" 
       ng-change="onMasterChange(master)"></input>
```

I created  as default: `$scope.master = false;`

```
....
 $scope.master = false;

$scope.onMasterChange = function(master){

     for(var i = 0; i < $scope.votes.length; i++) {
      $scope.votes[i].cb = master;
     }
};

$scope.change = function(value) {

  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.votes.length; i++) {

    //if($scope.votes[i].cb == undefined){
     // $scope.votes[i].cb = false;
   // }        

    if($scope.master == true){
       $scope.votes[i].cb = $scope.master;
       $scope.votes[i].status = value;

    }
    else if( $scope.votes[i].cb == true) {
      $scope.votes[i].status = value;
    }
  }
};
```

See <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d6nHDDf0oWgM2V2ORiAx?p=preview)</kbd>

Hope it will help,

Comment: This is doing exactly what I wanted without adding `watch`. I must accept this answer

Comment: I don't believe this works? Check all, then un-check a box, then change the status. The unchecked box changes status too.

Comment: @BCotter sure, because on any uncheck of child the `master` should be unchecked. But im not interesting to implement full logic. This is not SO scope.

Comment: @BCotter by the way if you interesting how to make master to disable on child change i added directive in Plunker

Answer (score 1):

It is working, but I believe ng-model is taking precedence over ng-checked. If you remove ng-model from the checkboxes, ng-checked is working as expected.

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="master"></input>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/q35JlhOVSGxmu6QW8e98?p=preview

It is important to note, however, that ng-checked does not update your model, it only changes the presentation of the checkbox. A way of tackling this would be to remove the master binding, and call a method with ng-click on your master checkbox which changes .cb on each box.

Edit: Working version using a watch on the master checkbox.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3NwGtp1FX8g9bfMrbWU5?p=preview

Comment: It is still not working when I'm using the master `checkbox` and try to change all to status approved it won't change.

Comment: I have in `select element` `ng-changed` define that call a function that does that. But it is not working when I'm using the master, only when I select `checkbox` slaves

Comment: Here is a working version. I set up a watch on master which sets the master value to each vote.cb value. http://plnkr.co/edit/P5hBFam0aDswIts9a0jr?p=preview

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem: 1. I click master `checkbox` 2. I try to change status 3. nothing happens.   Your last Plunker is still not doing what I've asked -> I think you've pasted my Plunk instead of yours

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't save it! One moment.

Comment: Thanks, `watch` seems to do the trick. Can you explain why the `ng-change="change()"` didn't call the `function` `change()` that was suppose to do what you did with `watch`?

Comment: Change seems to be working to me - It's calling it when you change your drop down option.

Comment: Yes but change does not work when I'm using the master `chekbox`

Comment: You want the status to change the moment you click the master checkbox? 

If you click master, then change status, all the statuses are changing. That seems correct to me?

Comment: When I click master it check everything, then I go to the `select` and change status -> Now `ng-change` is not working and I don't understand why? You overridden this problem with `watch`, but I want to understand why it didn't work with `ng-change`

Comment: Ng-change is working, it's just that you weren't changing your model when you checked or unchecked master, you were only putting a tick in the checkboxes. The watch function I put in actually updates your model, not just the checkboxes.